# Parsing CSS by regex

Tags: php, css, regex, css-parsing

I'm creating a CSS editor and am trying to create a regular expression that can get data from a CSS document. This regex works if I have one property but I can't get it to work for all properties. I'm using preg/perl syntax in PHP.

#### Regex

```
(?<selector>[A-Za-z]+[\s]*)[\s]*{[\s]*((?<properties>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)[\s]*:[\s]*(?<values>[A-Za-z0-9#, ]+);[\s]*)*[\s]*}
```

#### Test case

```
body { background: #f00; font: 12px Arial; }
```

#### Expected Outcome

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => body { background: #f00; font: 12px Arial; }
            [selector] => Array(
                [0] => body
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [0] => body
            )
            [2] => font: 12px Arial; 
            [properties] => Array(
                [0] => font
            )
            [3] => Array(
                [0] => font
            )
            [values] => Array(
                [0] => 12px Arial
                [1] => background: #f00
            )
            [4] => Array(
                [0] => 12px Arial
                [1] => background: #f00
            )
        )
)
```

#### Real Outcome

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => body { background: #f00; font: 12px Arial; }
            [selector] => body 
            [1] => body 
            [2] => font: 12px Arial; 
            [properties] => font
            [3] => font
            [values] => 12px Arial
            [4] => 12px Arial
        )
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any help - this has been confusing me all afternoon!

Comment: Could you please publish the part of the working code for this example?

Comment: @Khaled: I scrapped this project since I didn't really 'get' PHP parsers. When I get some time I'm going to look into implementing it in either PHP or C#.

Comment: No problem, I'm using now CSSTidy which is doing a nice job.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That just seems too convoluted for a single regular expression.  Well, I'm sure that with the right extentions, an advanced user could create the right regex.  But then you'd need an even more advanced user to debug it.

Instead, I'd suggest using a regex to pull out the pieces, and then tokenising each piece separately.  e.g.,

```
/([^{])\s*\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}/
```

Then you end up with the selector and the attributes in separate fields, and then split those up.  (Even the selector will be fun to parse.)  Note that even this will have pains if }'s can appear inside quotes or something.  You could, again, convolute the heck out of it to avoid that, but it's probably even better to avoid regex's altogether here, and handle it by parsing one field at a time, perhaps by using a recursive-descent parser or yacc/bison or whatever.

Comment: Agreed on the first part -- break down the problem.  But I don't see why this can't be a job for regex.

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced regex is indistinguishable from magic" - Misquote of Arthur C. Clarke (I think)

It could be a job for regex - the question is if regex is the right tool.

Comment: @harpo It is a job for a parser, the parser may use regexes to help it identify tokens, but you need more than just regexes to implement a parser.

Comment: Actually, the regex should be `([^{]+)\s*\{\s*([^}]+)\s*}` since there is more than one non-bracket character.

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to pull structure out of the data, and not just individual values.  Regular expressions might could be painfully stretched to do the job, but you are really entering parser territory, and should be pulling out the big guns, namely parsers.

I have never used the PHP parser generating tools, but they look okay after a light scan of the docs.  Check out [LexerGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator) and [ParserGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_ParserGenerator).  LexerGenerator will take a bunch of regular expressions describing the different types of tokens in a language (in this case, CSS) and spit out some code that recognizes the individual tokens.  ParserGenerator will take a grammar, a description of what things in a language are made up of what other things, and spit out a parser, code that takes a bunch of tokens and returns a syntax tree (the data structure that you are after.

Answer (score 11):

Do not use your own regex for parsing CSS.
Why reinvent the wheel while there is code waiting for you, ready to use and (hopefully) bug-free?

There are two generally available classes that can parse CSS for you:

HTML_CSS PEAR package at pear.php.net

and

CSS Parser class at PHPCLasses:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1289.html

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend against using regex's to parse CSS - especially in single regex!

If you insist on doing the parsing in regex's, split it up into sensible sections - use one regex to split all the `body{..}` blocks, then another to parse the `color:rgb(1,2,3);` attributes.

If you are actually trying to write something "useful" (not trying to learn regular expressions), look for a prewritten CSS parser.

I found [this cssparser.php](http://websvn.atrc.utoronto.ca/websvn/wsvn/Atutor/trunk/docs/include/classes/cssparser.php) which seems to work very well:

```
$cssp = new cssparser;
$cssp -> ParseStr("body { background: #f00;font: 12px Arial; }");
print_r($cssp->css);
```

..which outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [background] => #f00
            [font] => 12px arial
        )
)
```

The parser is pretty simple, so should be easy to work out what it's doing. Oh, I had to remove the lines that read `if($this->html) {$this->Add("VAR", "");}` (it seems to be a debugging thing that was left in)

I've mirrored the script [here](http://github.com/dbr/so_scripts/tree/master/csssparser.php), with the above changes in

Answer (score 6):

I am using the regex below and it pretty much works... of course this question is old now and I see that you've abandoned your efforts... but in case someone else runs across it:

```
(?<selector>(?:(?:[^,{]+),?)*?)\{(?:(?<name>[^}:]+):?(?<value>[^};]+);?)*?\}
```

(hafta remove all of the **/* comments */** from your CSS first to be safe)

Comment: How about with media query?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a piece of code that easily parses CSS. All you have to do is do a couple of explodes really... The $css variable is a string of the CSS. All you have to do is do a `print_r($css)` to get a nice array of CSS, fully parsed.

```
$css_array = array(); // master array to hold all values
$element = explode('}', $css);
foreach ($element as $element) {
    // get the name of the CSS element
    $a_name = explode('{', $element);
    $name = $a_name[0];
    // get all the key:value pair styles
    $a_styles = explode(';', $element);
    // remove element name from first property element
    $a_styles[0] = str_replace($name . '{', '', $a_styles[0]);
    // loop through each style and split apart the key from the value
    $count = count($a_styles);
    for ($a=0;$a<$count;$a++) {
        if ($a_styles[$a] != '') {
            $a_key_value = explode(':', $a_styles[$a]);
            // build the master css array
            $css_array[$name][$a_key_value[0]] = $a_key_value[1];
        }
    }               
}
```

Gives you this:

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [background] => #f00
            [font] => 12px arial
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of the current answer by Tanktalus there's a couple of improvements and edge cases to note.

### CSS Parsing Regex

```
\s*([^{]+)\s*\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}
```

This Regex will do some space trimming and hits on some additional edge cases as listed in this example: https://regex101.com/r/qQRIHx/5

#### key:value pairs; Pitfalls of Further Complexicated Regex

I too started to try work on delimiting the key:value pairs but quickly saw in the case where there were multiple styles per selector that things started to get trickier than I wanted. You can view version 1 of the regex where I tried to delimit the key:values and how it failed with multiple declarations here: https://regex101.com/r/qQRIHx/1

### Implementation

As others mentioned, you should break this up into multiple steps to parse and tokenize your css. This regex will help you obtain the declarations, but you will need to then parse those out.

#### Declaration Parser

You could use something like this to parse the declarations after you get your first set of matches.

`([^:\s]+)*\s*:\s*([^;]+);`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/py9OKO/1/

Edge Case

The above example works great with multiple declarations, but it's possible that it's just 1 declaration with no semi-colon to end which will render in [most] browsers but break this regex.

#### Noted Cases

You may also need to account for nested rules in the case that there's a media query. In this case I would try to run the css matching regex against the declarations that are extracted. If you get matches you could run recursion on it (although I'm not sure there's cases where you would have more than 1 level nested for vanilla CSS).

Edge Cases

- This doesn't handle a right curly bracket in a string

### Tomorrow's Research

I've decided to instead use an npm package like `css` or `cssom`. I know this is in PHP but it's going to do a lot of heavy lifting for me and handle edge cases I keep running into.

**Edit**:

I ended up using Jotform's public css.js library. It has a really small footprint which was one of the main requirements I had when choosing libraries to parse CSS.

- https://github.com/jotform/css.js/tree/master
- They also published this article explaining their process:

  - https://stories.jotform.com/writing-a-css-parser-in-javascript-3ecaa1719a43

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function trimStringArray($stringArray){
    $result = array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($stringArray); $i++){
        $trimmed = trim($stringArray[$i]);
        if($trimmed != '') $result[] = $trimmed;
    }
    return $result;
}
$regExp = '/\{|\}/';
$rawCssData = preg_split($regExp, $style);

$cssArray = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($rawCssData); $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $cssStyle['selectors'] = array();
        $selectors = split(',', $rawCssData[$i]);
        $cssStyle['selectors'] = trimStringArray($selectors);
    }
    if($i % 2 == 1){
        $attributes = split(';', $rawCssData[$i]);
        $cssStyle['attributes'] = trimStringArray($attributes);
        $cssArray[] = $cssStyle;
    }

}
//return false;
echo '<pre>'."\n";
print_r($cssArray);
echo '</pre>'."\n";
```

Comment: This does not work with nested @media ? Can you please modify and suggest.