# IF HTML element display is none, then do something, ELSE do something else - PHP

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get CSS style from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399210/get-css-style-from-php)

I want to make an `if` that will do things, only if div's display is not none. Here is an example:

```
<div id="div_1" style="display:none;">blah blah blah</div>
<?php if (div_1 display is none){...} else {echo $variable;} ?>
```

Any idea how will I syntax this part `(div_1 display is none)`??? If it can be of-course! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, no I didn't ask something like this!!!

Comment: Yes you did - you would have to use a CSS parsing library

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should tell us what the final product looks like, not only one way you think it can be achieved.

Comment: OK. I have made a function that runs a db query and I want to call this function only when `div` isn't `display:none`.

Comment: You can use AJAX and JavaScript

Comment: Any example or something please? Any link? Thank you for your answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that server-side. Maybe you can use JavaScript and Jquery is a good tool:

```
if($('#div_1').css('display') == 'none')
{
    ...
}
else {
    $('#Some_Div').html('...');
}
```

Comment: I see!!! And this example is Jquery right?

Comment: Why not just use `$('#div_1').is(':visible')`?

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an error? PHP executes first as server-side language, then javascript

Answer (score 1):

for non-jquery plain 'ol javascript

```
if (element.style.display == 'none'){
   //your element is not visible
} else {
   //your element is visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax and JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#div').is(':hidden')) {
$.ajax({
   url: "file.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {somedata: "data"}, 
      success: function(msg) {

       $("#div").html(msg);
      }
});
}
else {
//...
}
});
</script>
```