# Grab every css class name declared between curly braces using regex

Tags: php, css, regex

Hi Im trying to write a simple CSS parsing script in PHP that enables me to put previously declared classes within a css rule, i.e. the Mixins functionality of less and Sassy.

This regex only grabs the last css class name within the curly braces:

```
{.+(\.\w+).+}
```

For example, only .foo will be matched in the below css rule:

```
.login_form_container  { .gradient .rounded_corners width:431px; height:282px; margin:250px auto 0; .foo }
```

Thanks!

Comment: To be consistent, you'll probably want semi-colons after the class names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing CSS by regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236979/parsing-css-by-regex)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)?

Comment: Hey thanks for bringing this to my attention, I had been searching for something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this one:

```
{(?:[^\.]*(\.\w+))+[^\.]*}
```