# Get the width and height of each element's attribute via DOM or XPATH

Tags: php, php-5.3, domdocument, domxpath, getattribute

How can I get the width and height of each element's attribute?

For instance,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div class="item" style="width:295px; height:210px; border:1px solid #000;"></div><div></div>');

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node ) 
{
    $style = $node->getAttribute( 'style' );

    var_dump($style);
}
```

result,

```
string 'width:295px; height:210px; border:1px solid #000;' (length=49)
string '' (length=0)
```

but these are what I am after,

1. select the `div` that has the classname of `item` only.
2. get `295` (width) and `210` (height) only.

Is it possible with DOM? Or XPATH?

**EDIT:**

I seem to manage to select the div with the classname now,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div class="item" style="width:295px; height:210px; border:1px solid #000;"></div><div></div>');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); 

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@class="item"]') as $node) {

    $style = $node->getAttribute( 'style' );

    var_dump($style);
}
```

Now this is what I am after only,

get `295` (width) and `210` (height).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448005/implementing-condition-in-xpath-and-xquery/3448050#3448050 will answer the part about the XPath grabbing the div with a certain class attribute. You need regular string functions or a CSS parsers to break apart the inline style. This is not DOM's domain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432334/parse-inline-css-values-with-regex answers how to parse inline styles with regex

Comment: on a sidenote to get the style attribute of the div with the class attribute of item you can also do `//div[@class="item"]/@style`. This would return a DOMAttr then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a regex, you can use simple string functions to extract what you need. Here is an example, it most likely can be improved upon.

```
$width = 'width:'; $height = 'height:';
// Adding whitespace will not affect the result
$str = '    width:   295 px; height:   210 px; border:1px solid #000;';

$width_str = strstr( $str, $width);
echo 'Width: "' . trim( substr( $width_str, strlen( $width), stripos( $width_str, 'px;') - strlen( $width))) . '"';

echo "\n";

$height_str = strstr( $str, $height);
echo 'Height: "' . trim( substr( $height_str, strlen( $height), stripos( $height_str, 'px;') - strlen( $height))) . '"';
```

Of course, you can replace the `$width` and `$height` variables with their string literals, and remove the calls to `strlen()` as they would be constant integers.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hXiKa6)

Answer (score 2):

Style properties, as I recall, are "kebab-cased" -- IOW, they are expected to be all lowercase and all words are separated by hyphens.  Here's [one resource](https://www.quackit.com/css/properties/).

You have demonstrated a good choice by using a DOM parser to target your `div` elements with the `item` class.

The next step of parsing the style declarations would, again, be most reliable with a [CSS Parser](https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser), but if you are not interested in going to that effort, then a couple of `preg_match()` calls with discerning patterns should keep you in good stead.

For those who are not aware of fringe cases that may monkeywrench the outcomes for this task, I am adding a `title` attribute to one of the divs that will fool an inadequate pattern or DOM-unaware technique, and also adding a `line-height` declaration for the same reason.  These samples will catch many of the possible "shortcut" solutions that fail to parse the DOM.

The regex pattern must match the whole words `height` and `width`. My pattern will check that these words are at the start of the string or are preceded by a semicolon then zero or more whitespace characters. Once one of the words is found, the next non-whitesoace character must be a colon.  Then after allowing zero or more whitespace characters again, I use `\K` to "forget" all previously matched characters, then ONLY return the desired digital characters as the "full string match" (element `[0]`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dGRfb))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="items">
    <div class="item" title="Checking for bad parsing. height:666px; width:666px;" style="width:295px; height:210px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="item" style="line-height:14pt; border:1px solid #000; height :420px; width: 590px;"></div>
</div>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); 
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="item"]/@style') as $node) {
    $style = $node->nodeValue;
    echo "The height integer: " , preg_match('~(?:^|;)\s*height\s*:\s*\K\d+~', $style, $h) ? $h[0] : '';
    echo "\n";
    echo "The width integer: " , preg_match('~(?:^|;)\s*width\s*:\s*\K\d+~', $style, $w) ? $w[0] : '';
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
The height integer: 210
The width integer: 295
---
The height integer: 420
The width integer: 590
---
```

Comment: Related content: [Extract value from background-image style attribute with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056267/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetStyleValue($style, $type){
$value = false;
$all = explode(';',$style);
foreach($all as $part){
    $temp = explode(':', $part);
    if(trim($temp[0]) == $type){
        $value = (int)trim($temp[1]);
    }       
}
return $value;}
```

You can use this function to get `width`, `height` or other style value, just call:

`$width = GetStyleValue($img->getAttribute("style"), 'width');`