# Preg_match urls in css

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to match all the urls from a css I've been using with this regex and it was working very well.

```
@[^a-z_]{1}url\s*\((?:\'|"|)(.*?)(?:\'|"|)\)@im

Full match: url(https://example/product.png)
Group 1: https://example/product.png
```

the problem happened when i found a url like this:

```
background-image: url(/uploads/2019/03/product01-image(thumbnail_photo).jpg);


Full match url(/uploads/2019/03/product01-image(thumbnail_photo)
Group 1. /uploads/2019/03/product01-image(thumbnail_photo
```

I looked at this topic and tried to use some regex that exist with some modification

[preg_match to match src=, background= and url(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239013/preg-match-to-match-src-background-and-url)

the result was this

```
@(?:url\((?:\"|'|)(.*\.(?:[a-z_]{3}))(?:\"|'|)\))@im

Full match: url(/uploads/2019/03/product01-image(thumbnail_photo).jpg)
Group 1: /uploads/2019/03/product01-image(thumbnail_photo).jpg
```

At first it seemed to work fine but it is broken when I have a situation like:

```
.card-thumb__img1{display:block;width:142px;height:62px;background:url(https://example.com/product01.jpg) center center no-repeat;background-size:contain}@media (max-width:1029px).card-thumb__img2{display:block;z-index:1;background:url(https://example.com/product02.jpg) center center no-repeat #000;

Full match: url(https://example.com/product01.jpg) center center no-repeat;background-size:contain}@media (max-width:1029px).card-thumb__img2{display:block;z-index:1;background:url(https://example.com/product02.jpg)
Group 1:https://example.com/product01.jpg) center center no-repeat;background-size:contain}@media (max-width:1029px).card-thumb__img2{display:block;z-index:1;background:url(https://example.com/product02.jpg
```

How can I solve this and get the expected result for all situations?

**Edit**
Some types of occurrences that I have to match

```
url(https://exemples.com/fonts/lato/lato/lato-regular-webfont.ttf)
src:url(https://exemples.com/fonts/lato/lato-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix)
background:url(https://exemples.com/product/header/img.png)
background:url(/product/header/img.png)
background:url("/product/header/img.png")
background:url('/product/header/img.png')
background:url(/uploads/2019/03/0002-image(thumbnail_product).jpg)
```

Comment: Please show us all types of occurrences of URLs in your CSS code.

Comment: I'm not certain a browser would even recognise that kind of URL correctly... a bare URL (which is already a potential issue - you should quote those) containing parentheses? I mean what if your filename were `())(())))()()).png`?

Comment: This is why regular expressions should not be used as parsers. Use a proper library. A search turned this up: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, one option could be to recurse the first subpattern `(?1` and use a second capturing group for the url.

The url will be in capturing group 2.

```
url(\(((?:[^()]+|(?1))+)\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N8ssOX/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/OGaOq)

**Explanation**

- `url`
- `(` First capturing group

  - `\(` Match `(` char
  - `(` Second capturing group

    - `(?:[^()]+|(?1))+` Match either 1+ times not what is listed in the character class or recurse the first subpattern and repeat 1+ times
  - `)` Close second capturing group
  - `\)` Match `)` char
- `)` Close first capturing group

This will also match the leading and trailing `"` and `'` of a url. You could do another check when getting the matches using a capturing group to verify if the starting type of quote is the same as the end type of quote.

For example:

```
$re = '/url(\(((?:[^()]+|(?1))+)\))/m';
$str = 'background:url("/product/header/img1.png") and background:url("/product/header/img2.png\' and background:url(/product/header/img3.png"))';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (preg_match('/^([\'"]?)[^"]+\1$/', $match[2])) {
        echo trim($match[2], "'\"") . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
/product/header/img1.png
```