# Javascript - check if string is valid CSS color?

Tags: javascript, css, colors

If a color string is a number, then we can use a `RegExp` to check if it's a valid CSS color. But what if it's a word?

I have code that generates controls dynamically from colors arguments. But instead of color, there could be `null`, `""`, or random words. Is there a way to check color name with Javascript?

**Update:** Thank you much for the great answer! :)
My final version is below (added a `toLowerCase()` check because the color could be `"Green"`, `"Red"`, etc.).

```
function isValidColor(strColor) {
  var s = new Option().style;
  s.color = strColor;

  // return 'false' if color wasn't assigned
  return s.color == strColor.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: you have 140 names https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp so check them all .. good luck

Comment: that links to a jQuery answer for a non-jQuery question, overly complex as usual...

Comment: >>"it a commentary for someone how did 0 effort.." - keep calm, life is beatiful)

Comment: @dandavis i know, i was simply replying to someone who said my comment is ridiculous (he deleted his comment) to show him that with some research we can find a lot of ways, jQuery or not jQuery .. and based on this we can at least do an attempt then we can post question if we face issue. I guess this is how the site works, if am not wrong :) or should we encourage people to consider this website a Free coding service ?

Comment: i just knew a quick way of doing it and didn't see any good answers already. it's a simple question, but it's not the kind of question that results from mis-implementation; so it's hard for OP to show prior work. Look at what by vote accounts is a good question (no research at all):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-you-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Note that [color names are case-insensitive in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#html4).

Comment: It seems to be everyone here is using the `new Option()` constructor instead of `document.createElement('div')`. Is there some advantage to this? Am genuinely curious, I didn't know you could make option elements like this, but JSBench seems to find `document.createElement('div')` slightly faster.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a simple function that checks color name support in the current browser:

```
function isColor(strColor){
  var s = new Option().style;
  s.color = strColor;
  return s.color == strColor;
}

// try it out
isColor("red");   // true
isColor("reds");  // false
```

Since an invalid CSS property value will not persist, we can compare an attempted set value with the value we meant to set, and if they match, we know the color/property is valid.

Note this will also approve hex, RGB, etc. You can screen those out with a `RegExp` or two if that's an issue for your application.

Comment: Thank You much! Great! updated question with final version

Comment: Nice and pretty. Would give it a heart eyes emoji

Comment: When you pass a hex as a argument, it transform it to rgb (IDK why). Checking if `s.color` has value is enough to know if the color is valid or not.

Answer (score 71):

The accepted answer is almost correct, but some color values will be converted on some browsers -- at least Chrome converts hex RGB values `#000000` to `rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

However, if you set the `style.color` to an invalid value, you will get an empty string when checking it:

```
const isColor = (strColor) => {
  const s = new Option().style;
  s.color = strColor;
  return s.color !== '';
}
```

As Jonh Smith noted in the comments, the above also returns `true` for the keywords `unset`, `initial`, `inherit`. Whether these should be counted as valid colors probably depends on the application/context"

Comment: Note that this function returns 'true' also for the global keywords (unset, initial, inherit) - Whether these should be counted as valid colors probably depends on the application/context.

Answer (score 53):

I needed to validate CSS colors and all other attributes. I found [this wonderful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64550463/10332846) to be shorter and more robust as it uses built in [Web APIs CSS.supports()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports) method.

```
CSS.supports(propertyName, propertyValue)

CSS.supports('color','red') 
//True.
CSS.supports('color', '#007')
//True. 

CSS.supports('color', 'random')
//False. 
CSS.supports('colours', 'red')
//False.
```

Comment: Excellent. I think today that should be the best answer.

Comment: But this does not work on the node side

Comment: @Autumn, you mean it can cause problem in next js?

Answer (score 5):

I'm developing an application accepting color names or hex colors. 
dandavis' answer works just fine for the color names but does not work for hex colors.
The value stored in `s.color (when assigning '#ff0000')` is a RGB code (in this case `rgb(255, 0, 0)`). Therefore, the comparison `s.color == strColor` returns `false`.

Therefore, you need to combine dandavis' solution and the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027423/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-hex-color-representation/8027444).

Could look like this:

```js
function isColor(strColor){
  var s = new Option().style;
  s.color = strColor;
  var test1 = s.color == strColor;
  var test2 = /^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(strColor);
  if(test1 == true || test2 == true){
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `rgba(47, 79, 79, 1)`?  This return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic solution to test any CSS property value:

```
function validCssValue(cssProp,val){
    if(cssProp == "length") return false;
    if(val == "") return true;
    var style = new Option().style;
    if(style[cssProp] != "") return false;
    style[cssProp] = val;
    return style[cssProp] !== "";
}
```

All properties of `new Option().style` will be empty when created. Only valid values will update a property, so invalid values will leave the property empty. (Length is a property of the style object, but not a CSS property, so we need to reject trying to test it.)

Comment: Awesome, just I get confused: if we pass an empty value (empty string `""`) I think this is considered as a not valid CSS property, not? or it's will deleting the property itself from the element style. so, is not wise to return false instead of true in the third line?

Comment: For my purposes, empty is a valid value, because that would unset the css property. If your implementation sees empty as invalid, you could change line three to return false.

Answer (score 1):

The input is often incorrect with the output. If you check the length of the values, you get either an empty string or a value in the CSS2 tree

```
function isColor(string) {
    var s = new Option().style;
    s.color = string;
    return s.color.length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<p class="red"></p>
<p class="yellow"></p>
<p class="white"></p>

$(funtion(){
var obj = $("p");
var ex = $(obj).eq(1);

   $("button").click(funtion(){
   alert(obj);
  });
});
```

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Greetings Mr.Yannick! No) I need to dynamically check if color 'name' is valid html color