# JavaScript - Regular Expression to Validate Hexidecimal Color

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in JavaScript to see if a string is a valid hexidecimal color. From my understanding, hexidecimal colors can be 3-6 characters long (if you ignore the leading '#'). Each character must be in the range of A-F, a-f, and 0-9. In an attempt to write this regular expression, I have the following:

```
let value = 'abcxyz';
let rex = new RegExp('[A-F0-9]{3,6}', 'i');
let result = rex.test(value);
console.log(`value: '${value}' is a hexidecimal color: ${result}`);
```

Oddly, this prints:

```
value: 'abcxyz' is a hexidecimal color: true
```

I do not see how `value` can possibly match the regular expression provided. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hope this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484767/javascript-check-if-string-is-valid-css-color

Comment: You get a partial match for `[A-F0-9]{3,6}` that is why `.test(value)` is true

Comment: Check[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235414/3832970). `^` and `$` make the regex match only the whole string.