# How do I find the value of an input?

Tags: javascript

How do I make the color of the box be the value of the input?

```js
box = document.getElementById("box");
typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor");

function changeBoxColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor;
}
  
//box is a div, typeColor is an input
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="typeColor" placeholder="Type a color...">
<button onclick="changeBoxColor()">Change Box Color</button>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: You've retrieved the element, but you need the element's value: `typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor").value;`

Comment: your  code has a syntax error; is that just a paste issue?

Comment: body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


THIS IS THE CSS

Comment: I moved your comment to the snippet

Comment: Fix the typo of the extra `}`  use the value. `box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;`

Comment: How do you plan to do validation on the value for entries like "not a color"

Comment: I am unsure how.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the OP can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135216/can-i-check-if-a-css-property-is-valid-with-jquery/64550463#64550463, but seems to be more than what is being asked currently.

Comment: You should make sure you declare your variables properly with `let` or `const` or (at the very least) `var`. [Some information](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/).

Comment: the whole answer might be `document.getElementById("typeColor").value;`

Answer (score 0):

change color setting line as follows.

```
box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;
```

```js
box = document.getElementById("box");
typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor");

function changeBoxColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="typeColor" placeholder="Type a color...">
<button onclick="changeBoxColor()">Change Box Color</button>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working code snippet

```js
box = document.getElementById("box");
typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor");

function changeBoxColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="typeColor" placeholder="Type a color...">
<button onclick="changeBoxColor()">Change Box Color</button>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply type the text on input box and in your code **instead of typeColor please use the typeColor.value** you can fill the box with the provided color name on that box.

Thank you.

```js
box = document.getElementById("box");
typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor");

function changeBoxColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;
}
  
//box is a div, typeColor is an input
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="typeColor" placeholder="Type a color..." value="Red">
<button onclick="changeBoxColor()">Change Box Color</button>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a input tag field.

### Syntax

Return the value property:

```
let returnValue = inputObject.value
```

Set the value property:

```
let someNumber = 23;
inputObject.value = someNumber
```

Transfered to your code example:

```
box = document.getElementById("box");
typeColor = document.getElementById("typeColor");

function changeBoxColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = typeColor.value;
}
//box is a div, typeColor is an input
```

More about that can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_number_value.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Why make it simple when you can make it very complicated?

```js
const 
  box     = document.getElementById('box')
, btColor = document.getElementById('btColor')
  ;

btColor.onchange = () => 
  {
  box.style.backgroundColor = btColor.value;
  }
```

```css
 
#box {
  width       : 100px;
  height      : 100px;
  background  : red;
  margin-left : 100px;
  margin-top  : 50px;
  }
```

```html
<input id="btColor" type="color" value="#FF0000"> 
 
<div id="box">
</div>
```