# PHP RegEx: Remove CSS rules, except if contain specific string

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm struggling to match and keep all CSS rules containing the string `224,13,78`.

Sample input:

```
h1 {
    color: rgb(224,13,78);
}


h1 {
    display: block; /* Delete this whole block */
}


#test-color {
    color: rgb(224,13,78);
}    


.test-position {
    position: absolute; /* Delete this whole block */
}


.test-bg-color {
    background-color: rgba(224,13,78,0.5);
}


@media ( max-width: 1200px ) {
    .test-color {
        color: rgb(224,13,78);
    }

    .test-position {
        overflow: hidden; /* Delete this whole block */
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
h1 {
    color: rgb(224,13,78);
}


#test-color {
    color: rgb(224,13,78);
}


.test-bg-color {
    background-color: rgba(224,13,78,0.5);
}


@media ( max-width: 1200px ) {
    .test-color {
        color: rgb(224,13,78);
    }
}
```

Is there a handy regex that solves my problem?

For reference, I found this solution, but it matches the property name, not the value:

Find: `\{.*(font-size\:\s*\d+px\;).*\}?`

Replace: `\{ $1 \}`

And also this JavaScript solution that does the same:

[What is RegEx to remove css keeping font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415545/what-is-regex-to-remove-css-keeping-font-size/17415755#17415755)

I accept a JavaScript solution too, but PHP is preferable.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
\h*+[^\s{}][^{}]*{(?:[^{}](224,13,78)?)++[^{}]*+}(?(1)(*SKIP)(*F))\R*
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Q9W14l/4)

What it does is trying to match a sequence of characters `224,13,78` in a `{...}` block. If it matches it holds the value in the first capturing group. Then later we say if 1st capturing group was successful in matching, then skip over whatever has been matched by:

```
(?(1)(*SKIP)(*F))
```

otherwise the whole match doesn't contain the desired characters and engine won't skip over it. We now only need to replace matched blocks with nothing:

```
$css = preg_replace('~\h*+[^\s{}][^{}]*{(?:[^{}](224,13,78)?)++[^{}]*+}(?(1)(*SKIP)(*F))\R*~', '', $css);
```

Comment: Excelent @revo, it works, thank you! Do you have a idea to clean any other property inside every matched block and keep only the line containing `224,13,78`? 

Input:

`h1 {
 position: absolute;
     color: rgb(224,13,78);
 display: block;
}`

Output:

`h1 {color: rgb(224,13,78);}`

Comment: My pleasure. Just run another `preg_replace` on the previous output with this `\s*[^\s:{}]+:((?!224,13,78)[^;])*+;`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/Q9W14l/3

Comment: Great, you helped me a lot. Thank you again!

Comment: revo can you make the first RegEx also consider line breaks between selectors and delete them? Check here https://regexr.com/42b6t

Comment: Yes, but it will remove leading newline characters as well which makes CSS less readable. Try `\h*[^\s{}][^{}]*{(?:[^}](224,13,78)?)+[^}]*}(?(1)(*SKIP)(*F))\R*` instead.

Comment: I see... it solved, i think the last fix is not to match the opening brace that wraps the block, but limit the match to the selector braces, see: https://regexr.com/42b6t

Comment: Nice! The second RegEx, I found it breaks media rules and pseudo elements, see: https://regexr.com/42bd6

Comment: Replace `[^;]*` with `[^;{}]*`.